# Seeking Indy TCP demo for Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, tcp, delphi-7, indy

I have been to the Indy download page but the only link to a TCP demo (the final one on the page) links all seems to be broken. There were also some demos mentioned there to be found in Yahho groups but that page has vanished.

Does anyone know where I can find a very simple Indy demo of TCP client/server (preferably without SSL, just to keep it simple)? Just sending some data, maybe with an Ack ...

Thanks in advance for your help.

---

Answer: (for anyone else with a similar question) I am going to study [Exchanging Data over the Network using Delphi](http://delphi.about.com/od/networking/l/aa112602a.htm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what download page you visited, but all of the links on the official [Indy demos download page](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Demos/) work fine for me, minus the last one (which is a third-party demo).  And the [Indy-Demos Yahoo group](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/indy-demos/) is still around.

Comment: +1 for non-broken links. I ought to have phrased the question better. However, the  broken link is the only one that will actually help me. I just want to exchange data, not STMP, WhoIs, Finger, etc.  Thanks, as always, for your help, Remy

Comment: Did you look at the Indy 9 demos on that same page yet? They can be adapted to Indy 10, if that is what you are using.

Comment: @Remy, the last link for SSL example is now [here](http://adg.bmpcoe.org/download/indyssl/index.html) ;)